# ¿How can i predict missing data?

Tags: math, methods, statistics, prediction, predict

i have an array with some data that does not change, these data are the first but it is generating some data that i don't know and that i want to predict, what method could i use to predict it and that it does not change the data that i already had.
[image: array with missing data]

i have tried with some regression method but it seems to me that it is a lot of work because i would have to take  rows or columns and approve it for each one, in addition, the data has a alightly random behavior until it stabilizes at a percentage and from then on it is maintains